# O Datepicker do Angular Material não funciona

Tags: angularjs-directives, angular-module, angular

Tenho estudado programação Frond-End e tomei várias dicas de amigos sobre AngularJS e me indicação alguns sites de demostrativo de AngularJS, no momento estou tentando implementar Datepicker e não estou tendo resultado.

[CLIQUE AQUI PARA VOCÊ VER O DEMOSTRATIVO DO ANGULARJS](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.7/demo/datepicker)

Acima você pode observar a implementação e também as linhas de código, de fato fiz do jeito que está no site, e está igualzinho como está no site mas não funcionar, veja abaixo;

```
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendário</title>


<style>
  HTMLJSCSS
.datepickerdemoBasicUsage {
  /** Demo styles for mdCalendar. */ }

  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage md-content {
    padding-bottom: 200px; }
  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage .validation-messages {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #dd2c00;
    margin: 10px 0 0 25px; }
</style>

    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
angular.module("datepickerBasicUsage",
            ["ngMaterial", "ngMessages"]).controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.myDate = new Date();
          $scope.minDate = new Date(
              $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
              $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
              $scope.myDate.getDate());
          $scope.maxDate = new Date(
              $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
              $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
              $scope.myDate.getDate());
          $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return day === 0 || day === 6;
          }
        });
    </script>       

</head>
<body>

<h4>Only weekends within given range are selectable</h4>
    < ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
        md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"
        md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></>
    <h4>With ngMessages</h4>
    <form name="myForm">
      <md-datepicker name="dateField" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
          required md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"
          md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>
      <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
        <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
        <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
        <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
        <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
        <div ng-message="filtered">Only weekends are allowed!</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Alguém consegui enxergar aonde está errado?

Aparece isso em tela

```
Only weekends within given range are selectable

< ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate">
With ngMessages

The entered value is not a date!
This date is required!
Date is too early!
Date is too late!
Only weekends are allowed!
```

ATUALIZAÇÃO///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;' ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
    <h4>Disabled date-picker</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" disabled></md-datepicker>
    <h4>Date-picker with min date and max date</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
        md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
    <h4>Only weekends are selectable</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
        md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>
    <h4>Only weekends within given range are selectable</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
        md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"
        md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>
    <h4>With ngMessages</h4>
    <form name="myForm">
      <md-datepicker name="dateField" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
          required md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"
          md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>
      <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
        <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
        <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
        <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
        <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
        <div ng-message="filtered">Only weekends are allowed!</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso provavelmente está acontecendo por que você não estla atribuindo nenhum controller a seu HTML usando a tag ng-controller, você apenas estla o instanciando ...

Comment: como eu faria isso?

Comment: resposta detalhada abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema parece ser a falta de declaração do ng-controller no **html**. toda vez que você instância o controller no `js` do seu `app` você precisa indicar qual página ele será usado no seu `html`, isso porque você pode ter multiplos `controllers` com funções diferentes para serem usados em páginas diferentes, assim surge a necessidade de identificação.

Como na página do Angular Material mostra, o HTML é envolto pela seguinte `div`.

```
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;' ng-cloak>
    ... página aqui ...
    </div>
```

Que é o que falta no seu caso. Lembre-se que toda vez que desejar que uma função que foi declarada no `controller` então o seu uso no `html` tem que acontecer **dentro** da delimitação das tags, e não apenas na mesma página.

Exemplo de o que não funcionaria.

```
<body>
<div>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>{{ count }}</p>

</div>

<button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
});
</script> 
</body>
```

[Veja **não** funcionando no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5cuaLoa/)

Pelo fato de apesar da chamada da função `ng-click` ser usada na mesma página onde está o `controller` mas ela não pertencer ao `controller` isso não funciona. O correto seria usarmos a chamada da função dentro da div que está declarando o `ng-controller`.

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click Me!</button>
<p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
});
</script> 
</body>
```

[Veja funcionando no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swjLdfeq/1/)

Comment: você poderia dá uma olhada! fiz uma atualização. é porque eu tinha copiado errado, agora o resultado em tela é que não aprece nada dessa vez.